# Google Photos on the web not recognizing my pets but on Android, is recognizing them

Tags: google-photos

I have activated the option of facial recognition including pets. Strangely, in Google Photos on the web (Windows), it does not show pets inside recognized faces, but on Android it does.

It seems to be an old issue: [Google Photos is not recognizing pets](https://support.google.com/photos/thread/33187/google-photos-is-not-recognizing-pets?hl=en). I'd like to know if anyone else has the same problem and a solution

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Are you able to give more details? Are you sure that you are using the same account on on the web app and on Android app? How about try this feature using a public photo of a pet and share it so others could try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes, it's the same account. It seems to be an old issue: https://support.google.com/photos/thread/33187/google-photos-is-not-recognizing-pets?hl=en. I'd like to know if anyone else has the same problem and a solution...

Comment: Apparently there are many having the same problem... the last reply on the referred thread says "Populating pets faces often weirdly takes up to 3 weeks, so you have to be patient". When did you uploaded you pet photos?

Answer (score 0):

I am having the identical issue.  My app allows me to search for my dogs name and does a great job finding photos. When I log in on a PC, that is not an option. My workaround was to use the app, create an album, add people/pets, choose my dog (because that works in the app) and then when I go into the PC I can at least look at the album to find photos.  Not sure if it will continue to add new photos when uploaded, need to keep an eye on that.